# Mount folder using SSH in Kubernetes / Azure

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, sshfs

I'm able to mount a folder using SSH when I run my docker container locally (outside Kubernetes/Azure):

```
docker volume create --driver vieux/sshfs -o sshcmd=[user]@[IP]:/location_on_server -o password=[password] -o allow_other ssh_share

docker run -d -v ssh_share:/location_in_container my_image
```

How can I do the same in Azure / Kubernetes? What should I put into the deployment yaml / or maybe there is some workaround?

I found this solution https://github.com/chr-fritz/csi-sshfs but I can't use it on production since it's in an experimental stage.

If this is not possible or recommended using SSHFS, what's the easiest solution in which the files will stay on the same remote linux server?

Comment: What's in these files?  Can you use some other network protocol to access them, for example HTTP?  Or can you bundle them into the images that are running into your cluster?

Comment: My docker app should save large XML files to this folder on the remote server. And another app running on that server will use it once a day. 
Ideally it should be done using SSH because it doesn't require any work with our administrators, but if it's not possible, then I would like to choose an easiest alternative solution.